# Dispatching generic tasks in WCF or .Net Remoting

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, remoting

I've been researching for a couple days on and off, and have yet to figure out the best way to achieve the following goal.

I would like to define either an interface or abstract class in C# which has an associated Run method, similar to the Java runnable interface.  The goal would be to have a shared queue which contains a list of these objects.  Then individual clients would be able to derive their own concrete runnable classes and add them to the queue hosted by the server.  Clients would also be able to pop these runnable objects off the queue and execute them arbitrarily.

This seems like it should be feasible in a VM based language without needing to place any of the concrete implementations in a shared assembly, but I have thus far had no luck finding a working example of such a system.

Does anyone know how this might be achieved?

Comment: Are you envisioning the code executing all on the server? Or would it execute on the clients?  (Knowing that will tell if your clients need the concrete implementation installed, as well as how much information would need to be serialized and deserialized in order to invoke the Run method.)

Comment: The code should ideally be able to execute on any arbitrary client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out the [Agatha](http://code.google.com/p/agatha-rrsl/) project.  It provides a simple request/response layer for WCF.  As far as adding new "Run" implementations, you would use an IoC container or [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) to register new endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards MEF.  Very useful framework for plugin extensions.